# Calculating probable hits to page

Tags: python, hashmap

I am  newbie to python .Just wondering what kind of data structure should we use to solve this problem
What will be the probablity of user1 going from A ->B ,A ->C 
and user2 going from B->A and B->D

user    landing destination
1   A   B
1   A   B
1   A   B
1   A   C
1   A   C
2   B   D
2   B   A

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you could use defaultdict(list) with keys being users and values in lists would be tuples of (page from which user came from, page at witch user landed)

This gives you fast user lookup, and smaller lists of visits, so calculating probabilities for users, and adding new data will be quite fast